# checking id to set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I'm doing a jeopardy board, and I've given each div (each question square) an id in the index.html so when it's clicked, the correct question appears. I also wanted to set the point value for each div based on its id, so I used the jquery .is and this if/else statement. I've only done the code for A1 and A2, but while A2 should be worth $200, it's coming back worth $100. Why?

```
if ($('.well').is('#A1', '#B1', '#C1', '#D1', '#E1')) {
questionValue = 100;
}
else if ($('.well').is('#A2', '#B2', '#C2', '#D2', '#E2')) {
questionValue = 200;
}
else if ($('.well').is('#A3', '#B3', '#C3', '#D3', '#E3')) {
questionValue = 300;
}
else if ($('.well').is('#A4', '#B4', '#C4', '#D4', '#E4')) {
questionValue = 400;
}
else if ($('.well').is('#A5', '#B5', '#C5', '#D5', '#E5')) {
questionValue = 500;
}
```

Thank you in advance. Please let me know if I should include any more code. .well is the div class for the question squares.

Adding html code

```
<div id="wrapper">

     <div class="row">
       <div class="title"><h2></h2></div>
        <div class="question">
        <form> Your Answer:
      <input type="text" id="answer" /></form>
      <button id="submit">Submit</button>
      <p id="instruct">When you're sure about your probably wrong answer, click submit</p>

     <!--  <div class = "result"> </div> -->

    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
       <div class="well" id="A1">  <p>$100</p>  </div>
       <div class="well" id="B1">  <p>$100</p> </div>
       <div class="well" id="C1">  <p>$100</p>  </div>
       <div class="well" id="D1">  <p>$100</p>  </div>
       <div class="well" id="E1">  <p>$100</p>   </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="well" id="A2"> <p>$200</p>    </div>
       <div class="well" id="B2"> <p>$200</p>    </div>
       <div class="well" id="C2"> <p>$200</p>    </div>
       <div class="well" id="D2"> <p>$200</p>    </div>
       <div class="well" id="E2"> <p>$200</p>    </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="well" id="A3">  <p>$300</p>   </div>
       <div class="well" id="B3">  <p>$300</p>   </div>
       <div class="well" id="C3">  <p>$300</p>   </div>
       <div class="well" id="D3">  <p>$300</p>   </div>
       <div class="well" id="E3">  <p>$300</p>   </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="well" id="A4"> <p>$400</p>     </div>
       <div class="well" id="B4"> <p>$400</p>    </div>
       <div class="well" id="C4"> <p>$400</p>    </div>
       <div class="well" id="D4"> <p>$400</p>    </div>
       <div class="well" id="E4"> <p>$400</p>    </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="well" id="A5"><p>$500</p>     </div>
       <div class="well" id="B5"><p>$500</p>      </div>
       <div class="well" id="C5"><p>$500</p>      </div>
       <div class="well" id="D5"><p>$500</p>      </div>
       <div class="well" id="E5"><p>$500</p>      </div> 
    </div>
    <h3> score = </h3>
    <div class = "score">0</div>

</div>
```

And this is how I'm doing each question.

```
$("#A1").click(function() {

             $(".question").show();
             $('<h4>The \"MVP\" quarterback whose team is 14-6 when he doesn’t play.</h4>').appendTo('.question');
             $('#submit').click(function() {
                 $("#answer").on('input')
                    var answer = $('#answer').val(); //what does this mean in words? 


                    if 
                        (answer == "Tom Brady" || answer == "Brady" || answer == "brady" || answer == "tom brady") {
                        $('.question').replaceWith('<h3>omg you\'re so smart</h3>')      //using h3 because it'll be unique, but there must be a better way
                        score += questionValue;
                        $(".score").text("$" + score);
                    }
                    else 
                        {
                        $('.question').replaceWith('<h3>could NOT have been more wrong</h3>');
                        score -= questionValue;
                        $(".score").text("$" + score);
         }
```

});
                            });

Comment: How is the `"well"` class set? `$('.well').is('#A1', '#B1', '#C1', '#D1', '#E1')` will be true if *any* element has both the class `"well"` and one of those ids - perhaps you meant `$(this).is(...)`, assuming that code runs in a click handler where `this` would be the clicked item? (Also, not the problem, but it seems to me it would be a lot neater to set common classes for each level rather than testing all the IDs like that.)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Please add your HTML code too.

Comment: Why not just use the combination of selectors ? If you want to check if an element has class `.well` and id `#A5` just write your selector `$('.well#A5')` to select all those matching elements .

Comment: added html code. FYI I'm a beginner, so it's almost certain there's a better way to do pretty much everything.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you have implemented so far may be correct but I guess its very difficult to maintain that code. Also for any new person t will be quite uneasy to understand that logic. Please have a look at below approach. You may refer it and take an idea out of it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".well").click(function() {
    var quesVal = $(this).data("questionvalue"); //reading the questionvalue associated with each question
    alert(quesVal);
  });
});
```

```css
.questionContainer {
  width: 250px;
}
.questionContainer .well {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  /*Here you can also use display: inline-block instead of float:left*/
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionContainer">
  <!--Putting question value in each and every box along with id and class as a data- attribute -->
  <div class="well" id="A1" data-questionvalue="100">A1</div>
  <div class="well" id="B1" data-questionvalue="100">B1</div>
  <div class="well" id="C1" data-questionvalue="100">C1</div>
  <div class="well" id="D1" data-questionvalue="100">D1</div>
  <div class="well" id="E1" data-questionvalue="100">E1</div>
  <div class="well" id="A2" data-questionvalue="200">A2</div>
  <div class="well" id="B2" data-questionvalue="200">B2</div>
  <div class="well" id="C2" data-questionvalue="200">C2</div>
  <div class="well" id="D2" data-questionvalue="200">D2</div>
  <div class="well" id="E2" data-questionvalue="200">E2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to make this work. Doesn't seem ideal cause I have to add more code over and over, but I'll take it. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick - yes..thats true. You will have add more code in hTML but your JS code will become of just few lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
$('.well').click(function(){
if ($(this).is('#A1')||$(this).is('#B1')||$(this).is('#C1')||$(this).is('#D1')||$(this).is('#E1')) {
alert(100);
}
else if ($(this).is('#A2') ||$(this).is('#B2')||$(this).is('#C2')||$(this).is('#D2')||$(this).is('#E2')) {
alert(200);
}
})
```

it may be length way but works.

Fiddle [test](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6Sx/327/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplification (this does not address your particular implementation – but simplifies it in a way that could fix your problem)

You could use classes instead of using specific IDs for each cell, and have 5 of each 1 through 5 and A through E:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- row 1 -->
    <div class="r1 a"></div>
    <div class="r1 b"></div>
<!-- blah blah -->
    <div class="r5 d"></div>
    <div class="r5 e"></div>
</div> <!-- row 5 -->
```

**For reference:** I use `r` as a first letter because you can't start a class name with a number.

Then in your JavaScript:

```
if($('.well').is('.r1')) questionValue = 100;
```

and so on.

**For reference:** You can skip the curlybraces `{}` in an `if` statement if the contents are one line (such as in this example).